# How set maximum concurrent requests per instance in Kubernetes to 1?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to dedicate each vm to each user.
In [cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency) it is simply working by set maximum concurrent requests to 1, however cloud run does not support gpu and it is not an option for me.
How is it possible on Kubernetes? I am running Unreal Engine on VMs and this should not be shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Kubernetes out of the box. But install [KNative](https://knative.dev/docs/) and you will be able to achieve it (and you will be able to reuse the same YAML service definition as Cloud Run, because Cloud Run implements the KNative APIs)

Comment: Thanks. If I use KNative, can I access the IP of the instance? So if a user is added, then I know which instance IP is assigned to each user?

Comment: Do you want to do only HTTP, or TCP/other protocol? Why IP is important?